# Using Java 8 Streams for hiearchy of classes

Tags: java, java-8

```
finalList= resultList.stream()
    . filter(nestedDo -> nestedDo.getAttrib8() == 'S' &&
            nestedDo.getFirstChildList().stream()
            .filter(c -> 
                    ("ST2".equals(c.getAttrib18()) || 
                     "ST3".equals(c.getAttrib18()) || 
                     "ST4".equals(c.getAttrib18()) 
                                                       &&
                         c.getGrandChildList() != null &&
                         c.getGrandChildList().stream()
                            .filter(gc -> 
                            date.after(gc.getAttrib19()) &&
                            date.before(gc.getAttrib43())
                            )
                            .findAny().isPresent())
                            )
                            .findAny().isPresent())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

NestedCustomerDO50 is a class which is inherited by NestedFirstChildDO50 which is inherited by NestedGrandChildDO50. Each class contains List of the child class(i.e NestedCustomerDO50 contains List of NestedFirstChildDO50 and NestedFirstChildDO50 contains List of NestedGrandChildDO50). Each class contains 50 attributes(attrib1-atrib50).

resultList and finalList are list of object of type NestedCustomerDO.

getFirstChildList() returns the arrayList of objects of type NestedFirstChildDO50
getGrandChildList() returns the arrayList of objects of type NestedGrandtChildDO50

Here finalList contains filtered result based on filtering of all levels. But I want to get resultList as finalList if resultList gives a result(not null) based on filtering of second and third levels. So whenever the second and third level filtering returns a result I want to get the parentlist with full childlist.

eg: if NestedCustomerDO50 holds customer details and NestedFirstChildDO50  holds address details and NestedGrandtChildDO50 holds City details, when we search it by above code we get only specified filtered result, but I want all customer details including all addresses(Not the specified filtered address).

If any doubt in the question, please add as a comment.

Comment: You shouldn’t ask questions based on obfuscated code. You are talking about “customer details”, “City details”, etc. but all we see in your code is `getAttrib18`, `getAttrib19` and `getAttrib43` in `ChildList` or `GrandChildList`. How are we supposed to know what a customer or city is in that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is as cryptic as your code but as far as I understand, you just want to know whether there is any match and if so, use the entire original list and the filtered (then empty) list otherwise.

This is the right point to learn about [`anyMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which will not only solve your task but also simplify your inner conditions as you can replace `.filter(element->condition).findAny().isPresent()` with `.anyMatch(element->condition)`

```
List<?> finalList = resultList.stream()
  .anyMatch(nestedDo -> nestedDo.getAttrib8() == 'S' &&
    nestedDo.getFirstChildList().stream().anyMatch(c -> 
          "ST2".equals(c.getAttrib18())
       || "ST3".equals(c.getAttrib18())
       || "ST4".equals(c.getAttrib18()) 
          && c.getGrandChildList()!=null
          && c.getGrandChildList().stream().anyMatch(gc ->
              date.after(gc.getAttrib19()) && date.before(gc.getAttrib43()))
  ))? resultList: Collections.emptyList();
```

Note that I kept the logic of the innermost condition exactly as in your question though the brace placement looked suspicious to me.